# Java and Selenium: Collect website values and get the statistics of which data (color) appears more frequently

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am a very newbie and  I am scraping a website using Java and Selenium. I am collecting 3 colors generated by a website per match and I want to get the statistics of which color appears most frequently in the last 5 matches. When my program starts, I will manually input the colors for the last 5 matches, and it will generate a color suggestion for the next match. Then, I need to collect and store the values for the incoming matches so that I can continue making predictions for the next colors. The latest ones appear on the left so I can get the xpath, but I do not have any idea how to store and compute the statistics. Can anyone walk me through?

[image]

Above is the picture which shows the colors name by letter: B for blue, Y for Yellow, and so on. I want to store them as string colors.

I can collect the xpath with no problem but I do not know how to store these letters and compute the statistics. I have very very limited knowledge of java.